# XCode error: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Failed to open diagnostics file")

Tags: xcode, firebase-authentication, xcode13

I tried to integrate Google Firebase Authentication into my XCode project but when I entered the initialization code in my AppDelegate and ran the build it gave me the error: "Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Failed to open diagnostics file")". Not sure what is wrong so any assistance would be helpful.